# Docker image repository name or tag for environment versioning

Tags: docker, devops

Was hoping to get some advice for the best approach for creating Docker images for deployment over several environments.  Assuming we have 3 environments - DEV, UAT & PRD would it be best to name the image accordingly along with a version tag i.e.

```
my-service-dev:release-10
my-service-uat:release-8
my-service-prd:release-6
```

or keep the repository the same but use the tag:

```
my-service:dev-release-10
my-service:uat-release-8
my-service:prd-release-6
```

We are using Bamboo as a build/deploy pipeline so can easily append build/release variables.

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you should use the same image in all environments, so that when you push an image to production you're running the exact code you ran in the test environment.  You don't need text like "release" in the tag either, and if you look at standard Docker Hub images it's common enough for the tag to just be a number.

```
my-service:10
```

If your CI system can generate sequential build numbers these can work fine.  If developers are building test images themselves it may be more convenient to use a time stamp or source control commit ID.

```
my-service:20201111
my-service:g52fc7a0
```

If you really need different builds in different environments, standard Docker Hub images encode details like that in tags.  For example, the [`python` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) has variants `python:3.9-alpine` and `python:3.9-buster` (Debian).  Often a top-level image name is a "unit" in a registry; you might need to use a tool like Terraform to create a new image name in AWS ECR, but you can push arbitrarily many tags once the image name exists.

```
my-service:10-test
my-service:11-prod
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes code base is the same and any environment specific configs are dealt with but passing env variables/using profile switch (spring boot).  Current build process is split into independent build and deploy stages.  The Docker image is built onto a build server my-service:build-x, there may be more commits & builds before it is deployed.  At deploy stage latest build image is tagged to my-service:release-x and pushed to a private registry. Bamboo variable is used for the release version which will be release-x.  I think for transparency it makes sense to use that in the tag.

Comment: doesnt this require you have different container registry for each environment?  how can i guarantee that  a restart in QA does not pull in the same image in dev if you use the 'promotion' principal that the same image should move through the env pipeline.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "restart" here?  The goal of this approach is in fact to run the exact same image in dev, test, and production environments.  You wouldn't modify or republish an image after it's built.